# Android Floating popup 'window' options?

Tags: android, dialog, popup

I wish to have an 80% by 80% sized view popup, grey out the background and take focus?

In essence it's a "sub" view that is model.

Strategies ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an activity with the dialog theme by specifying it in the manifest like this:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

This will cause it to be a popup as described.  To achieve the 80% x 80%, you need to configure your activity's layout to take up that much space.